# I exceeded the Google Sheets time limit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was making a code to separate articles from different sheets and then I took it to a specific sheet. The problem is that being so many articles it takes too much time to separate them and sometimes it fails due to time limit, does anyone know how to simplify it?

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reparacion de cilindro de puerta G7'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 10);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 10, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(1, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:F12').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Ultimos 10 movimientos'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Reparacion de cilindro de puerta G7\'!A3:F12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A32').activate();
```

It is not the whole code, it is only one article.

(I don't speak English, I'm using the translator. Sorry if this is misspelled. I'm not a programmer either, so sorry if it's too bad, haha.
Thank you very much.)

Comment: Rewrite the code without using activate() and setActiveSheet()

Answer (score 0):

Your script is exceeding the 6 minute quota.

Try this:

This applies @Cooper 's comment to avoid using `activate()` and `setActiveSheet()`.

**Major changes**

- `var g7Sheet` - this defines the sheet once and enables reuse of a variable name
- `g7Sheet.insertRowsAfter(12, 10);` - simplifies code to one line
- `rangeList.setValue(f2Value);` - 20 lines of code are devoted to copying the contents of cell F2 to F3:F12. This change does the same thing in 3 lines.

---

```
function copyarticle() {
  // start with G7 sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var g7Sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reparacion de cilindro de puerta G7')
 
  // inserts 10 rows after row 12
  g7Sheet.insertRowsAfter(12, 10);

  // copy F2 to F3:F12
  var f2Value = g7Sheet.getRange("F2").getValue()
  var rangeList = g7Sheet.getRangeList(['F3:F12']);
  rangeList.setValue(f2Value);


  // copy G7 A3:F12 to Ultimos sheet
  // select A3:F12
  var ultimosSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Ultimos 10 movimientos')
  g7Sheet.getRange("A3:F12").copyTo(ultimosSheet.getRange("A3:F12"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  // select ultimos a32
  ultimosSheet.getRange('A32').activate();
}
```

---